# Remove duplicate elements in an ArrayList without using HashSet

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

My logic is messed up. I am just trying to work out a way to remove duplicates in an ArrayList without using a HashSet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> wordDulicate = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordDulicate.add("Tom");
    wordDulicate.add("Jones");
    wordDulicate.add("Sam");
    wordDulicate.add("Jamie");
    wordDulicate.add("Robie");
    wordDulicate.add("Helen");
    wordDulicate.add("Tom");
    wordDulicate.add("Troy");
    wordDulicate.add("Mika");
    wordDulicate.add("Tom");

    for (String dupWord : wordDulicate) {
        if (wordDulicate.equals(dupWord))
            System.out.println(wordDulicate.get(dupWord));
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you can create a new list and add items to it.. skipping duplicates..

Comment: Just out of curiosity or is use of `HashSet` prohibited by the teacher? :)

Comment: how is `for (int dupWord : wordDulicate) {` compiling?

Comment: `dupWord` should be a `String` not an `int`

Comment: Nope, I just prohibited the easy way. Wanted to learn the tough way :) So, I can love HashSet even more.

Comment: You compare one entry of the list with the whole list `if(wordDulicate.equals(dupWord))`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This methodology requires having another list:

```
       ArrayList<String> wordDulicate = new ArrayList<String>();

        wordDulicate.add("Tom");
        wordDulicate.add("Jones");
        wordDulicate.add("Sam");
        wordDulicate.add("Jamie");
        wordDulicate.add("Robie");
        wordDulicate.add("Helen");
        wordDulicate.add("Tom");
        wordDulicate.add("Troy");
        wordDulicate.add("Mika");
        wordDulicate.add("Tom");

        ArrayList<String> nonDupList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Iterator<String> dupIter = wordDulicate.iterator();
        while(dupIter.hasNext())
        {
        String dupWord = dupIter.next();
        if(nonDupList.contains(dupWord))
        {
            dupIter.remove();
        }else
        {
            nonDupList.add(dupWord);
        }
        }
      System.out.println(nonDupList);
```

Output:

```
[Tom, Jones, Sam, Jamie, Robie, Helen, Troy, Mika]
```

Comment: Why are you removing from original list?

Comment: I thought that was requirement, if NOT, we can do just ! (NOT) check.

Comment: I'm new to Iterator. Can I ask why you used to Iterator?

Comment: Iterator allows you to loop through the collection. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: So, is that the best way to loop through a collection?

Comment: Take a look at the for-each-loop, too. It makes use of the Iterator interface and reads much easier.

Comment: This is throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 9):

You can create another list, and add items to it, skipping the duplicates: -

```
ArrayList<String> wordDulicate = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tempList= new ArrayList<String>();

wordDulicate.add("Tom");
wordDulicate.add("Jones");
wordDulicate.add("Sam");


for (String dupWord : wordDulicate) {
    if (!tempList.contains(dupWord)) {
        tempList.add(dupWord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should sort the list and remove the element that is equal to the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Seems little late to the party, but with single arraylist,

Here's the code without hashset...

```
strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("a1");
    strings.add("a2");
    strings.add("ss");
    strings.add("asd");
    strings.add("asd");
    strings.add("a1");
    strings.add("ss");
    strings.add("ss");
    System.out.println(Collections.frequency(strings, "ss"));
    for(int i = 0; i< strings.size();i++){
        int frequency = Collections.frequency(strings, strings.get(i));
        if(frequency>1){
            String string = strings.get(i);
            for(int j = 1 ; j < frequency ; j++)
                strings.remove(string);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Collections.frequency(strings, "ss"));
    System.out.println(strings);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListDuplicateRemove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


       List<String> lst = new LinkedList<String>();
        lst.add("ABC");
        lst.add("ABC");
        lst.add("ABCD");
        lst.add("ABCD");
        lst.add("ABCE");

        System.out.println("Duplicates List "+lst);

        Object[] st = lst.toArray();
          for (Object s : st) {
            if (lst.indexOf(s) != lst.lastIndexOf(s)) {
                lst.remove(lst.lastIndexOf(s));
             }
          }

        System.out.println("Distinct List "+lst);

    }

}
```

Comment: You should explain what your code is doing, and how it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
package arraylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Student{
    String name;
    String dob;
    public Student(String name, String dob) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name+"\t"+dob;
    }
}

public class RemoveDuplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("prakash", "89"));
        list.add(new Student("prakash", "89"));
        list.add(new Student("saurabh", "79"));
        list.add(new Student("saurabh", "79"));

        Iterator<Student> it=list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

        int size=list.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<size-1;j++){
                if(list.get(i).getName().equals(list.get(j).getName())){
                    list.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList l2 = new ArrayList();

Iterator iterator = l1.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        YourClass o = (YourClass) iterador.next();
        if(!l2.contains(o)) l2.add(o);
    }
```

l1 is the original list, and l2 is the list whithout repeated items (Make sure YourClass has the equals method acording to what you want to stand for equality)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0;true;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter your Element:");
     String s1= sc.nextLine();
     if(s1.equals("Exit")){
         break;
     }
     int x1= Integer.parseInt(s1);
     al.add(x1);

     for(int j=0;j<al.size();j++){
         for(int k=j+1;k<al.size();k++){

             int temp;
             if(al.get(j).intValue()>al.get(k).intValue()){
                 temp =al.get(j).intValue();
                 al.set(j, al.get(k).intValue());
                 al.set(k, temp);

             }//if
         }//for
     }//for
}//for
System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: Here we can add one by one integer element from console to our java class by using scanner class object and after that we can check for the element sorting

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[]args){
       ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
       al.add("Tom");
       al.add("jerry");
       al.add("mike");
       al.add("jerry");
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(String dupli : al){
           if(!names.contains(dupli)){
               names.add(dupli);
           }
       }
       System.out.println(names);
    }
```

Comment: It's great you're trying to contribute, but this is really a bad answer. First it is a code only answer, you haven't explained at all why this is an answer. Second the question explicitly says: "Without using a HashSet" your edit fixed that I suppose. Third, what does this offer that is different than the previous answers?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).